# Randomly shuffling a matrix in python in a way that isn't completely hideous

Tags: python, matrix, shuffle

For a DataScience application, I need to randomly shuffle the rows of my matrix before I get to work on it.

Is there a way to do this that isn't just taking the index, shuffling the index, and then passing the shuffled index to the matrix?  As in:

```
    indx = np.asarray(list(range(0, data.shape[0], 1)))
    shufIndx = shuffle(indx)
    data = data[shufIndx,:]
    return (data)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

With `python` (not `numpy`), you can directly `random.shuffle` the rows:

```
import random

matrix = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

print(matrix)
random.shuffle(matrix)   # random.shuffle mutates the input and returns None
print(matrix)
```

#### sample output:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
[[7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

Answer (score 0):

numpy.random.shuffle() should do the trick

```
import numpy as np
mat = np.array(range(16)).reshape(4,4)

print(mat,'\n')

np.random.shuffle(mat) 

print(mat)
```

Output:

```
[[ 0  1  2  3]
[ 4  5  6  7]
[ 8  9 10 11]
[12 13 14 15]]

[[12 13 14 15]
[ 4  5  6  7]
[ 0  1  2  3]
[8  9 10 11]]
```